# why my PWA app is installed as a link when is downloaded from the playstore.... and as a native app when is coming from chrome installation?

Tags: installation, browser, progressive-web-apps, nativeapplication

I have this PWA app https://www.oubil.com and when I download it from the playstore(Oubil)... it is installed as a link and if I click the installed icon on my phone, it is open  almost like is a browser session, with the URL address field and everything... but if I open first the chrome browser and open the  https://www.oubil.com URL, the app asks me if I want to install it. If I do so, the app is installed as a native app(like it should be) and if I click the installed icon on my phone, it's open like a native app(like it should be).

What am I missing? :D

I set up the manifest.json with this:   `"display": "standalone"`
I put my assetlinks.json on the .well-known folder in my server
and I double check with the lighthouse tool that my app covers all what is need to be a PWA app

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to a missing of `assetlinks.json` in your pwa website's root directory. 
You should make `.well-known` folder at root directory and paste `assetlinks.json` into the folder. For example, `assetlinks.json` should be accessed with the link `https://<URL to your PWA>/.well-known/assetlinks.json`. You can also make repository named `.well-known` and upload `assetlinks.json` on the repository if you are running pwa website with CRA and Github-Pages. 
For more description, check this documentation. https://docs.pwabuilder.com/#/builder/android